# Intercepting a PHP module with frida

Tags: elf, frida, php

I have a PHP module, and I'm trying to hook the functions of that module.

```
...
    39: 0000000000024a60  1858 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   12 zim_ClassName_ClassName_exec
...
    90: 0000000000028f10     8 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 get_module
...
    93: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND zend_execute
...
```

Frida enumerateSymbols will show this:

```
{
    "address": "0x7f21a5a9ea60",
    "isGlobal": false,
    "name": "zim_ClassName_ClassName_exec",
    "section": {
        "id": "12.text",
        "protection": "r-x"
    },
    "size": 1858,
    "type": "function"
}
```

And enumerateExports:

```
[
    {
        "address": "0x7f011d0a2f10",
        "name": "get_module",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "address": "0x7f011d07bdc0",
        "name": "_init",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "address": "0x7f011d0a2f18",
        "name": "_fini",
        "type": "function"
    }
]
```

(note: my php file contains sleep(3) before calling the function)

```
$ php test.php &
$ frida-trace -i "*exec*"` php
  ... hooks 52 functions, none matching that class' actual function
  ... sleep(3) ends and the function gets executed
  1948 ms  zend_get_executed_scope()
  1948 ms  zend_get_executed_scope()
  1948 ms  zend_get_executed_scope()
  ... lots of same line
  1954 ms  zend_execute()
  1954 ms     | execute_ex()
```

I'm unable to intercept any of the exports above. I'm getting `Error: module.so: unable to find export 'get_module'`.

`frida-trace` will load the 3 exports above, I guess that's because php loads the module and calls get_module before frida has a chance to intercept it.

Is it possible to intercept `zim_ClassName_ClassName_exec`, which is the php function I want to work on? Is frida the right tool for that? Thanks!

Comment: update: I was able to use runkit7 to intercept the PHP functions and get the job done, but I'd still like to learn how to hook symbols

Comment: If the library is loaded dynamically at run-time I would try to hook `dlopen` and if it returns test if your module containing the method is loaded. If it is loaded, hook it. Hopefully `get_module` should be called after dlopen returns.